# Can officewriter help to resolve SSRS excel export(with merged cells) row-height issue

Tags: reporting-services, officewriter

I am evaluating Office writer for the following problem that we are facing with SSRS excel export. Could someone advise how can we use OfficeWriter to resolve this issue.

Problem Statement : 
Our client requires a report with nested groups in an excel format. They use this report for analysis and  further manipulation. Due to nested groups the rows and columns get merged and the row-height is not automatically adjusted to the text.  The text in these cells are therefore not visible.

I understand that this can be done  using a macro or passing the report through an  ExcelApplication code. But I want to understand if this can be done using the native SSRS report (with the design created in the reportbuilder) and just passing that excel file to a piece of code(either macro or excel application). Or if I would need to rewrite the report format in OfficeWriter Designer as a template and that template gets sent to the code on runtime.

Comment: Not sure if this solves the problem, but could you just pass the report to ExcelApplication and do an Autofit which should adjust the row height.

Comment: Thanks Sam. That is what I would like to do but for that do I still need to create an ExcelTemplate and then pass it to the code or can I use my SSRS excel export to pass to the ExcelApplication? I am not quite sure how to implement this.

Comment: Moved comment to answer, now that I understand your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your exact infrastructure, but you ExcelApplication can open an excel file from stream, or disk. You can call reporting services via a web service call, and pass the SSRS generated file to ExcelApplication.  You wouldn't need to use ExcelTemplate in this case, but you might need a middle man to do the WebService call.

See SoftArtisans documentation on this http://blog.softartisans.com/2013/05/13/kb-how-to-open-a-report-from-sql-server-reporting-services-with-the-application-object/